# Spin Control Position Issue (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm having an issue with a spin (up/down) control. In the properties for the spin control, I have "Set Buddy Integer" set to true.

In my dialogboxproc's WM_INITDIALOG, I am setting its buddy to a static text control:

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_SETBUDDY, (WPARAM)GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC1), 0);
```

I am also setting the minimum/maximum range and the starting position:

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(1, 1));
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_SETPOS, 0, 1);
```

When a certain button is hit in my dialog box, I am updating the range and position:

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(2, 1));
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_SETPOS, 0, 2);
```

(I was using a variable to set the range and position but because I am having problems I am manually setting it as I have just posted.)

Directly after setting the position, I double check it just to confirm:

```
LRESULT lr = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_GETPOS, 0, 0);
WORD pos = LOWORD(lr);
```

Indeed, the position is 2.

Next, I click the down arrow on the spin control. The static text buddy changes from a 2 to a 1. Here is what my WM_NOTIFY code looks like in the dialogboxproc:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
        ncode = ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code;

        switch(ncode)
        {
        case UDN_DELTAPOS:
            {
                LRESULT lr = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_GETPOS, 0, 0);

                if(HIWORD(lr) == 0)
                {
                    WORD pos = LOWORD(lr);

                    //Other stuff here
                    return TRUE;
                }
```

After pressing the down arrow and checking the value of pos, the position is still 2. I had previously set the position to 2 and pressed the down arrow. Shouldn't the position be 1 at this point? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but I'm not sure if it's the best or intended way to do things. If you cast the lParam to type LPNMUPDOWN:

```
LPNMUPDOWN lpnmud  = (LPNMUPDOWN)lParam;
```

You can get the current position and the proposed change in position. By adding the current position and the proposed change, you can get what the new position would be:

```
int newPos = lpnmud->iPos + lpnmud->iDelta;
```

Then, you have to manually get the range and check whether or not the new position would be within in the boundaries of the range. It seems like a lot of work but I guess that is the way its normally done.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `TRUE` in the `UDN_DELTAPOS` handler, which instructs the control to disregard the change. Instead you should return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, after this line:

```
LRESULT lr = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_SPIN2), UDM_GETPOS, 0, 0);
```

I found that HIWORD(lr) always is 1, not 0. MSDN said the right result is 0, I don't know why too.

If you want to get the pos of Spin Control, you could try:

```
LPNMUPDOWN *lpnm;
lpnm=(LPNMUPDOWN)lParam;
WORD pos;
pos=lpnm->iPos;
```

By the way, through to judge the sign of lpnm->iDelta, you could know whick key of Spin Control is pressed.